# How to make all fonts available in Konsole/Yakuake?

Tags: gnome, fonts, konsole

At the moment I only have monospaced fonts and not all of them (I have the ubuntu monospaced font and it is not listed in the dialog).

**Update:** I forgot to mention that I use Gnome 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can edit the .kde/konsolerc file to specify the font you want.

Comment: Thanks, but it was in `~/.kde/share/apps/konsole/Shell.profile` for me.

Answer (score 2):

You only need close Yakuake or kill the process and relaunch Yakuake.

First check if the process exists:

> ps aux | grep yakuake

If the process exist, you can terminate it with killall:

> killall -9 yakuake

And then relaunch Yakuake, now Yakuake can load all your changes in your 
desktop environment.